# redirect any file/folder after domain name to domain itself

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I am trying to redirect any file or folder from it's location to the root.

For eg,

if the url is

http://www.abc.com/xyz

or

http://www.abc.com/page.html

then it should redirect to http://www.abc.com

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.abc.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^.+$ /
```

OR using `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.+$ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. It works but I am losing the css file. I mean the css is not working.

Comment: For CSS, JS. images etc make sure to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: I have done that but still is not finding the css. Really strange.

Comment: Fixed... I had to use only RewriteRule ^.+$ / [L,R=301]

Comment: One more thing that is it works for only one folder for example abc what if I have www.abc.com/xyz_d. It doesn't redirect?

Comment: It will redirect every file/folder to root `/`

Comment: Yes but for some reason it is redirecting for one folder not for another folder. :(

Comment: Well as you can see i this rule `.+` will match anything with 1 or more characters. Most likely you have some other .htaccess somewhere.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get a chance to test it...but will definitely do tonight or tomorrow morning. I will let you know about the o/p. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi Anubhava..sorry for replying late. It is working great. Actually the problem was that there was another htaccess working.So I had to deactivate that. One more thing , is it possible to redirect http://www.abc.com/folder1/folder2/file1.html to http://www.abc.com I mean any folder or any file after http://www.abc.com should redirect to http://www.abc.com.Many thanks.

Comment: Glad to know that rule is working fine for you. Above rule is already redirecting any `folder or any file after abc.com should redirect to abc.com`